# Can we load index.html page in native webview intead of cardova webview

Tags: ios, cordova

I am building hybrid for ios using cardova. intially what cardova is doing , it is loading index.html in webview. I just want the same index.html to load in my native webview instead of  cardova webview where i can use all the cardova features.
How can i go for this , what the steps for it. 
Why i need this because we have some pages completly in native and 80% in hybrid. So within html i can't call my native page right but within webview i can call native also and html also. How should i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a CordovaWebView into your native application. In this way you can build a native application that then also uses your Cordova hybrid pages. Check out the docs here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews

You will still need to use a CordovaWebView and not the native browser or WebView though because of all of the hooks and overrides that have been made to the WebView. (You may be able to take a look at the CordovaWebView files and duplicate that but it seems like more work that you'd want to do.)